# Why do I get a TypeError when refreshing the page saying a state isn't found when that's not really the case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-router

I have a `Wall` component where the user gets redirected from the `Login` component upon successful authentication.  Inside the `Wall` component, I'm calling `name` which's the user's name they've registered with.  All I'm doing here is greeting the user per the code.

The user's name comes through successfully.  However, when I refresh the page - I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` error but how's that so when the name's being displaying on the browser?

Is this issue persisting because it's inside `componentDidMount()`?  That's my only suspicion but I could be wrong.  What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix this in a way where whenever the user logs in successfully and refreshes the page, it persists with no issues?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Wall extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props.location.state.name);

        this.state = {
            name: ''
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({name: this.props.location.state.name})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello, {this.state.name}!</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Wall;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an error because you assigned an undefined to the state, name. 
Why?

Okay let me explain.  if you don't persist a data in something like local storage, and keep it in say something like a state, it will get destroyed after each rendering. So by refreshing your page, the data (name) coming from props gets destroyed.

To fix this,  in the authentication step of your app, save the logged in user info in a local storage and then pull that info directly from local storage instead of passing down as a prop.

Hopes that helps

Comment: ah ok, I gotcha.  I'm going to give that a shot.  thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. If it works for you,  don't forget to mark it as a solution.